# Java code error not sure what i am supposed to do?

Tags: java, swing

I bought a new book called "learning Java" and I am struggling with the following problem.

It asked me the type the code below, however now it says we are going to replace the JLabel with our own graphical class. HelloCompoent is the new graphical class that he wants me to create and it should display Hello Java.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Helloworld {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Hello, Java");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello world", JLabel.CENTER);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I tried

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Helloworld {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame (); 
        class HelloComponent extends JComponent{
              public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
                  g.drawString("Hello, Java", 123, 95);
                  frame.add(new HelloComponent());
              }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: You're probably supposed to create a new class called HelloComponent.

Comment: You're asking two things. You mention in your title an error, but here you show something that you need help with. Which is it? Can you show us what you tried for `HelloComponent` instead of making us guess as to the issue? Nobody can do such guesswork reliably.

Comment: @james this class should be in its own file, not inside the main() method. Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: You can't define a class inside your main.

Comment: @HugoSousa I'm not sure I've ever tried, because it is so uncommon, but AFAIK you can define local named classes.

Comment: @HugoSousa And here is the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html So indeed this is valid!

Comment: Have you tried to extend from JLabel ?

Answer (score 0):

After declaring your class you need to create an instance of it and add it to the frame:

```
    HelloComponent helloComponent = new HelloComponent( );
    frame.add(helloComponent);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

and you probably should remove the 
 frame.add(new HelloComponent());

from the paintComponent-method.

The paintComponent will only be called if an instance of the class is added to the component hierarchy of a visibile frame. So you have to add it to the frame before calling the paintComponent. Therefore you can remove it from that method.